# VS C# Express not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I have a problem and don't know what to do. I'm using Visual C# Express 2010, but sometimes, when I execute my code (F5), the debugger interrupts at some point with an exception, sometimes says "method not implemented" or "there is no source code available". Then, the IDE begins to do weird things. For example, when debugging step by step, it stops the cursor at blank lines, and the program doesn't work as expected. So when this happens, I need to overwrite the entire project with a previous backup. It's like all the project were corrupted.

This is an image of the editor:
[image]

And this is an image at Runtime:
[image]

I'd like to know what's is happening, and how to solve it, without loading a backup.

Thanks!

Comment: Hope you have not implemented interface with methods which have this line of code 'throw new NotImplementedException();' ?

Comment: Hi, there are no interfaces in the program

Comment: Are you sure you're performing Rebuild All before each execution? Looks like you're trying to debug an application with some changes without rebuilding it.

Comment: Hi, I'm building every project and rebuilding the entire solution before execution. But only overwriting with a backup, my program works again.

Comment: after seeing your image, it looks like an infinite loop. Where are you incrementing the value of i ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only solution was formatting my PC and reinstalling windows. After this, reinstall VS and no more problems.

Answer (score 1):

For any changes in the code, I would always suggest you to first rebuild the project and then running the programming whether in debug or direct mode. Changes to the code files don't reflect, if the solution isn't rebuilded.

About the Error : *method not implemented* - It is shown when a method from an abstract class or interface is not implemented in the dervied class.

*there is no source code* . This might be because of no build. Try rebuilding, it should not come again

Comment: Hi, I'm rebuilding the entire solution. Also I delete all the files from the debug directory before each rebuild. Then, when I hit F5, the code 'moves', and some breakpoints are not shown, others are created where I didn't place them, others are just not hit. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you're rebuilding your project, I would delete the output directory (typically, this folder is called Debug or Release, and contains the exe and pdb files), and see if that makes a difference. Maybe you think you are rebuilding, but you aren't.

Also, when you run your project, make sure you're running the same configuration you're building. If you build Release, but run Debug, the generated code will not match, even if the files are up to date.

You can get to the output path by going to the project Properties page, Build tab, and clicking on the Output path Browse button:

[image]

Remember that just because you haven't explicitly defined an interface, it doesn't mean that your program doesn't use interfaces. Code you're using may already implement interfaces with default code that needs to be overridden in your code.

As others have suggested, I would search for the string [`NotImplementedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx), just to make sure you aren't inadvertently throwing this exception somewhere in your code.

Also, I would change the code to catch the exception, so you can go up the stack and identify where it's being thrown:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    try
    {
        MyDevice.SetGpo(i, false);
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // set your breakpoint here
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm deleting all the files from the Debug directory, I'm not at release yet. Then rebuild the entire solution so the new files are placed there. But only a previous backup works. The message changes,  for example, in that for {} a 'timeout' exception is thrown. I've added images to show how the code 'moves'. Thanks for your help.